# ¿Por qué "Y" en el verbo "ir" para "YENDO"?

Tags: gramática, ortografía

¿Por qué el `Gerundio` del verbo ir, es el único que se escribe con `Y`?

e.g.

- ir
- iré
- iba
- ido
- ¿yendo?

Comment: ¡Porque el verbo *ir* es muy, *muy* extraña!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es una regla de ortografía. No se puede comenzar una palabra con una vocal débil que forma parte de un diptongo.

Para las combinaciones con *i + vocal*, se usa bien hache (*hi + vocal*), bien ye (*y + vocal*) según costumbre para cada palabra (y a veces se admiten ambas formas: *hierba*, *yerba*). Las combinaciones con *u + vocal* solo se hacen con hache (*hu + vocal*).

Para otros ejemplos de verbos que hacen cosas parecidas, tenemos *oler*, *erguir* y *errar*.

Comment: A mí me solían enseñar en el colegio la norma ortográfica de que si un verbo conjugado contiene un sonido /ʝ/ no presente en el infinitivo, se escribe con "y" y no con "ll". Ahora me doy cuenta de que existe un motivo etimológico histórico detrás de esta norma: "Et otrosí decimos que si **caiere** la lanza a algun Cavallero en **iendo** por la carrera ante de los golpes quel otro Cavallero, que alze la lanza e non le dé" (*Libro de la orden de caballería de la banda de Castilla*, 1332).